# How to validate a control that is in the form of a selected grid box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have a database that has around 1000 users and each user has one or more journal entries relating to them. On the left side of the page I have a search box where staff can search the database for a user and select a user. Once the user is selected from the left side search, the staff member can write a journal entry and it will add the entry to the database and will be put in a table related to the selected user via userid. Currently I get an error message if a staff member tries to submit a journal entry without selecting a user and I would like to implement some sort of custom error message, like a simple message box that says, "Please search and select user".

I thought my code below would work but it still redirects to the ASP.NET error page. Any ideas on what's going on?

```
protected void btnSubmitJournalEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text != "")
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please search and select user')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        //Start database connection
        string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Sites\App_Data\access.mdb";
        string cmdstr = "insert into JournalEntries(StudentID, Topic, SubTopic, JournalDate, Advisor, FaceTime, Notes, Followup, Author) values(@StudentID, @Topic, @SubTopic, @JournalDate, @Advisor, @FaceTime, @Notes, @Followup, @Author)";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
        con.Open();
        //The following fields are added from the journal entry form to the corresponding database fields
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", ddlTopic.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTopic", txtSubTopic.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JournalDate", txtDate.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Advisor", txtAdvisor.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaceTime", txtFacetime.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Followup", txtFollowup.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", ddlAuthor.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        //End
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Journal entry has been successfully added!')", true);
    }
}
```

This is the error message I keep getting.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 27:     protected void btnSubmitJournalEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 28:     {
Line 29:         if (SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text != "")
Line 30:         {
Line 31:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because `SearchGrid.SelectedRow` is NULL. And so when `SearchGrid.SelectedRow` is NULL, then the Cells are also NULL but yet you are checking if Cells[3] is there?

What you need to do is just check if the SearchGrid.SelectedRow is NULL, since you dont care which row is selected, you can do the following:

```
protected void btnSubmitJournalEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SearchGrid.SelectedRow == null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please search and select user')", true);
    }
    else
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep that did it! Thank you for the fast reply and explanation!